# Differences of body vs body_stream in HttpGenericRequest

Tags: ruby, http

What is the differences between `body` vs `body_stream` in Net::HttpGenericRequest. [Documentation says...empty.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html)

Example code:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.body = "ABCDEF"
req.body_stream = "ABCDEF"  # Any difference?
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference is in what kind of argument each one receives, as you can see at the documentation.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html#method-i-body-3D

**Net::HTTPGenericRequest#body** receive a **string** as argument.

```
req.body("ABCDEF")
```

**Net::HTTPGenericRequest#body_stream** receive a **input** as argument.

```
req.body_stream(File.open("/tmp/example.txt"))
```

I hope this helps you.